# How to retrieve data from Azure Cosmos Db with Core(SQL) API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Good Day,

I am developing an azure function with .net framework/V1 in Visual Studio, I want to retrieve the **clientDetails** datas from **TestData** collection on Azure Function, my function is HttpTrigger.
[image]

I tried the example from this link: [Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions 1.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb)

I created two property class:

```
    public class DocumentClient
    {
        [JsonProperty("clientDetails")]
        public List<ClientDetails> clientDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientDetails
    {
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string channel { get; set; }
        public string retailer { get; set; }
        public string store { get; set; }
        public string auth { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the constructor:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function), Disable()]HttpRequestMessage req, [DocumentDB(
        databaseName: "Client",
        collectionName: "TestData",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection"
       )] DocumentClient client, TraceWriter log)
```

but I am having an error **Id is required** when I run the function, but whenever I tried to add

```
Id ="{Hardcoded - the TestData's Id}"
```

I am having an error **"PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation"** when the function is triggered

I added this in my local.settings.json:

```
"CosmosDBConnection": "AccountEndpoint=https://test.com:443/;AccountKey=testkey==;"
```

Regards

Comment: how did you define your cosmo db schema >???

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an error "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this
>   operation" when the function is triggered

According to this error message, i think you need to set the partitionKey in your  `function.json` file.Please refer to this [supported properties list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#input---configuration).

> PartitionKey  Specifies the partition key value for the lookup. May
>   include binding parameters.

Here is a sample :

```
{
    "name": "inputDocument",
    "type": "documentDB",
    "databaseName": "MyDatabase",
    "collectionName": "MyCollection",
    "id" : "{queueTrigger}",
    "partitionKey": "{partition key value}",
    "connection": "MyAccount_COSMOSDB",
    "direction": "in"
}
```

Comment: I was able to run it by adding this to the json
"AzureWebJobsStorage"
"AzureWebJobsDashboard"
and the value of that is the connection string of my storage acc.
and I changed the constructor to:

    IAsyncCollector<DocumentClient> client

, but I am not able to see the client values yet .

Comment: @NicoTing Still crashed into the same error related to the partition key?

Comment: No, but I am not able to see the **clientDetails**